# How to export Excel predecessor data to MS Project?

Tags: excel, vba, import, export, ms-project

I have four columns in my workbook. e.g. ID Column can be ignored.

| ID | Task Name | Resource Names | Predecessors |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Task1 | Employee1 | 2 |
| 2 | SubTask1 | Employee2 |  |
| 3 | Task2 | Employee1 | 4,5 |
| 4 | SubTask2 | Employee2 |  |
| 5 | SubTask3 | Employee2 |  |

I am looking to create an Excel macro to export the contents into MS Project.

I can only find sharing in the web about transferring the Task.

My code, credit to #madschedules, only includes Tasks.

```vb
Sub createNewMSPFromExcelData()

' First go turn on the MS Project reference library

' Declare variables
Dim pjApp As MSProject.Application
Dim pjProject As MSProject.Project
Dim pjtasklist As MSProject.Tasks
Dim pjtask As MSProject.Task
'Dim pjpredlist As MSProject.TaskDependencies
'Dim pjpredlist As TaskDependencies
Dim pjpred As TaskDependency
Dim xlrange As Range
Dim xlrow As Long
Dim counter As Integer

'open MS Project application
Set pjApp = New MSProject.Application
pjApp.Visible = True

' Add a new project file
Set pjProject = pjApp.Projects.Add
Set pjtasklist = pjProject.Tasks


'Loop through all the Excel Data in the worksheet
counter = 2
Do Until Cells(counter, 1) = ""
    Debug.Print Cells(counter, 1).Value & "   " & Cells(counter, 2).Value & "   " & Cells(counter, 3).Value

    ' Add new task into MS Project from Excel Value
    pjtasklist.Add (Cells(counter, 2).Value)
    pjpred.Add (Cells(counter, 3).Value)

    counter = counter + 1
Loop

MsgBox ("There are " & pjtasklist.Count & vbNewLine & _
       " tasks in our new project")

End Sub
```

Expected data in MS Project
[image]

To answer about the predecessors, I am currently doing a project with electronic schematic design which deals with multi hierarchies. Hence to work on the hierarchy, I need to ensure the sub-hierarchy activities are done before I can proceed with the next level, hence I have the predecessors details derived from the schematic into Excel.

Comment: i am not sure how to define the content to be in the "resource names" & "predecessors" in MS Project. It currently only available for Tasks. Btw, I am not a script person, and mostly searching some ideas in the web and trying to enable it :). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to adding tasks and then setting task properties is to get a reference to the task object after it's added. So instead of:

```
pjtasklist.Add (Cells(counter, 2).Value)
```

do

```
Set pjtask = pjtasklist.Add (Cells(counter, 2).Value)
pjtask.ResourceNames = Cells(counter, 3).Value
```

Before going any further, however, clarity is needed regarding tasks, subtasks, and predecessors. In scheduling, a *subtask* is considered to be a task under a *summary task*. A summary task is used to group a related subset of the tasks for the project. The summary task's start and finish dates are calculated based on the earliest start and latest finish of its subtasks.

Predecessors are tasks that must happen *before* another task can start. Predecessor tasks should almost always be entered first so that the schedule reads in chronological order. Therefore it is extremely rare to see a task with a predecessor ID value higher than its own. Instead, the Excel table would be better like this where OL = OutlineLevel:

| ID | Task Name | Resource Names | Predecessors | OL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Task1 | Employee1 |  | 1 |
| 2 | SubTask1 | Employee2 |  | 2 |
| 3 | Task2 | Employee1 |  | 1 |
| 4 | SubTask2 | Employee2 |  | 2 |
| 5 | SubTask3 | Employee2 | 4 | 2 |

This yields the typical schedule structure like this:

[image: sample schedule]

And finally, here is the code to turn the table above into the schedule:

```
Sub createNewMSPFromExcelData()

Dim pjApp As MSProject.Application
Dim pjProject As MSProject.Project
Dim pjtasklist As MSProject.Tasks
Dim pjtask As MSProject.Task
Dim counter As Integer

Set pjApp = New MSProject.Application
pjApp.Visible = True

Set pjProject = pjApp.Projects.Add
Set pjtasklist = pjProject.Tasks

counter = 2
Do Until Cells(counter, 1) = ""

    Set pjtask = pjtasklist.Add(Cells(counter, 2).Value)
    pjtask.ResourceNames = Cells(counter, 3).Value
    pjtask.Predecessors = Cells(counter, 4).Value
    pjtask.OutlineLevel = Cells(counter, 5).Value

    counter = counter + 1
Loop

MsgBox ("There are " & pjtasklist.Count & vbNewLine & _
       " tasks in our new project")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rachel. Appreciate the answer provided. I did a quick trial using the code but I am seeing "Run-time error 91" - Object variable or With block variable not set when execution the
`
    'pjtask.ResourceNames = Cells(counter, 3).Value
    pjtask.Predecessors = Cells(counter, 4).Value
    pjtask.OutlineLevel = Cells(counter, 5).Value'
`

Comment: Is the line above it working? `Set pjtask = pjtasklist.Add(Cells(counter, 2).Value)` Make sure you have **Set pjtask = …** in there otherwise the object variable, pjtask, won’t be set.

Comment: Excellent, thank you Rachel for pointing out the line that i missed. I am able to move the data into respective columns but unfortunately it is not as desired. Whenever a task has predecessors, it automatically added task lines (empty lines) based on the predecessors items hence dictated the ID and reference. As an optional, will it be possible to just paste the content into MS Project instead? I can paste the predecessors info the last to avoid auto task line addition. Thanks again Rachel.

Comment: I think I managed to get the copy/paste working '' var = Range("Y1").Value Range("AA2").Select Selection.Resize(var).Copy pjApp.Visible = True SelectTaskField Row:=0, Column:="Resource Names" EditPaste ''.